# pandas index and columns in same line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multindex with two columns in a dataframe as follow

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 5, 6, 0], [2, 5, 6, 0]]),columns=['a','b','c', 'd'])
df

df.set_index(['a', 'b'],inplace=True)
df
```

That produces index in a different line of column header

```
     c  d
a b      
1 2  3  0
  5  6  0
2 5  6  0
```

How index and column can be put in the same line without missing index columns?

Desired output, index and columns in the same line

```
a b  c  d    
1 2  3  0
  5  6  0
2 5  6  0
```

Comment: Did you try this `df.reset_index()` ?

Comment: Index names and column headers are offset to distinguish indices from columns. They are different structures and have access to different methods. What do you need to change the DataFrame visualisation for? Are you exporting to something like excel or making a table in a jupyter notebook or to HTML?

Comment: Even when you have two columns as index, when you save it to excel file, it will becomes the original format again

Comment: Looks expected to me. Can you post a sample of your desired output?

Comment: I would like maintain index and have index and columns in the same line

Answer (score 0):

its true,
df.set_index(['a', 'b'],inplace=True).

then you used "print", printing change view(Change is only in vision.).
if you save dataframe, its save true.

[image]

Comment: It looks like this only works for excel. csv and latex save as it shown.

Comment: Write more information to help you. What do you want to do with operations?

Comment: I want the same results that you achived exporting to excel, but exporting to_latex. Well your solution works nice for excel, when I export to_latex the result is the same that I **print(df)** what it produces one row for columns and other row for index.

Comment: you can also:  print(df.to_string(index=False))___Prints what you want.      also: 
df.set_index(pd.Index(['']*len(df)), inplace=True)
print(df)      Note: Basically you cannot have a dataframe without an index.

Comment: What you are doing is removing the index. But I need the index.